# How to merge 2 identical UV islands into one?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

How do I make 2 UV islands that are exactly the same (2 shoes with legs) only one UV island, so that I in Photoshop, GIMP etc. only have to do half the work? I want to texture a pair of shoes and legs, by only having to texture 1 shoe and 1 leg. Like a mirror.

[image]

I overlapped them by moving them so they were on top of each other, but that didn't work apparently:

(UV Map exported to Paint.Net and edited for testing)

[image: UV Map exported to Paint.Net and edited for testing]

[image]

As you can see, the stripes of color do not appear symetrically on each leg, which I suppose should be happening when I have overlapped the islands. More detailed: 
1. I rotated some pieces that needed it 180 degrees so they were facing the same direction as the other piece
2. I flipped the biggest chunks on the bottom (using s+x+-1) that are supposed to be the legs and overlapped them as precisely as I could, manually with G. 
3. Now there was a lot of space on the UV map, so I scaled the islands a lot, to make use of the space.
4. And here I am, wondering why it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why overlapping UV's didn't work?

Comment: @batFINGER Hi, I updated my post. I don't really know why it didn't work, also the stripes that I painted on the legs appear on the shoes aswell for some reason...

Comment: Going by UV maps  think you only need s y -1 to each to match orientation